# Illegal character when trying to escape square brackets with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, escaping

Using the jquery form plugin.  I was trying to test the value of a form element that uses square brackets.

```
            var form = jqForm[0];
            if (!form.sendTo\\[\\].value) {                
              alert('Something'); 
              return false; 
            }
```

Despite trying to escape the brackets it is still giving me a an error.

illegal character

[Break On This Error] if (!form.sendTo\[\].value) {

is it not possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a square brackets and a string in place of dot-notation in javascript. So try this:

```
var form = jqForm[0];
if (!form["sendTo[]"].value) {                
   alert('Something'); 
   return false; 
}
```

---

Edit after comments:

Using jQuery you can determine how many checked checkboxes there are using code such as:

```
$('input[name="sendTo[]"]:checked',form).length
```

assuming `form` is a jQuery object referencing the form containing the checkboxes. if it's not, you should be able to wrap it like `$(form)` in the example above.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/TMSsq/

Comment: In looking at this further it appears that, while this works, this isn't exactly the whole picture.  The form element is actually part of a group of check boxes all with the name "sendTo[]".  Evidently what I need to do is figure out how to determine if any of the boxes has a value, as at least one of them is required to be checked.

Comment: I wasn't referencing the object correctly and your updated example did  the trick.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @oljones - glad it helped. Just FYI, you should click the little tick next to the correct answer on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as an associate array. Try this

```
        var form = jqForm[0];
        if (!form.["sendTo[]"].value) {                
          alert('Something'); 
          return false; 
        }
```